# xcode using view in subclass

Tags: ios, xcode, subclassing

I am learning to program the iphone and I wanted to do some drawing. I followed some example code and subclassed the viewcontroller and it worked fine. Now as I wanted to expand the program I came upon a design question that I could use a little help on.

I subclass myviewcontroller with mynewview. If I have any code in the myviewcontroller how do I call or reference it in mynewview and vice versa? I am not sure if I am asking this right but I am trying to understand the relationship between the class and subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C objects benefit from inheritance. All classes are subclasses of NSObject, therefore you can call init on any object. If you created a custom class and gave it a method doSomethingAwesome, you are free to then implement doSomethingAwesome in any subclass of your custom class. However, declaring a method in a subclass does not add that method to the superclass. As an aside, I rarely find myself subclass sing my own custom classes. I believe that it is encouraged to maintain what is called a shallow object hierarchy. Usually I subclass the stock cocoa classes, customize to my needs and if I need custom methods in more than one subclass I will declare a category on the superclass rather than relying on inheritance to provide my custom behavior

Comment: Thanks, this helped, I just needed a nudge in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The messaging system in Objective-C is dynamic. Every object includes a `struct` with information that the runtime use for introspection. Here the runtime will find a list of methods the object is able to respond. So, let's say you message an instance like this:

```
[mynewview someMethod];
```

The runtime will first check the object information to trying to find some method that will be able to respond the message. If nothing is found, then will query the super class, and so on. In fact, the runtime is much more complex, and will give any object more opportunities to respond (that's the dynamic part. For instance, `mynewview` might not have any method called `someMethod` and yet, might be able to satisfy the call, but that's something you might not want to worry right now).

From a child class you can call the superclass implementation of a given method with the keyboard `super`, so if `mynewview` is a subclass of `myviewcontroller` you can call `myviewcontroller` implementation from `mynewview` with:

```
[super someMethod];
```

If `someMethod` is both present in `myviewcontroller` and in `mynewview`, the runtime will automatically only call the child implementation, you have to call the parent implementation (if you have to) from the child implementation.